# How to compare contents of two cells of dynamic table

Tags: javascript

Im creating a game like candycrush. 3 random candies appear at a time in a row. Table is 9x9. Cells' contents are images. Now, if there are three or more same consecutive images, entire row gets deleted. Following is the `chechcombos()` function which is called at different intervals.

```
function checkcombos(){
    var counter=0;

    for(j=0;j<row;j++){
        for(i=0;i<col;i++){
            if( (document.getElementById("r"+j+"c"+i).innerHTML==document.getElementById("r"+j+"c"+i++).innerHTML )  ){
                counter++;
            }
            if(counter>=3){
                for(i=0;i<col;i++){
                    document.getElementById("r"+j+"c"+i).innerHTML="";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    alert(counter);
}
```

In above function, it simply traverses one row at a time and transverses all of its cells. If the next one matches the current then counter is incremented. Finally if counter value is either greater or equal to 3 then that entire row gets deleted. Now the problem is above condition gets true every time function is called.

Comment: Check your postfix operator in your comparison... it will increment (AFTER) the comparison... I think you want prefix (++i)

Comment: You should be reseting `counter` to zero when a non-match is found before it reaches three in a row. Also, please format you code for clarity.

Comment: A much better approach would be to have a data structure in your JavaScript that contains the state of the game, and let the UI simply reflect that.

Comment: @ElGuapo now condition doesn't even run at all

Comment: Change it in your if statement, not your for loop.

Comment: @ElGuapo I did change it in if like this :if( document.getElementById("r"+j +"c"+i).innerHTML==document.getElementById("r"+j+"c"+ (++i)).innerHTML  )        and Im calling it like this : 
setInterval(function f(){checkcombos()},4000);  in main function